# Can it is be replaced with were in the past?

Tags: question-tags

Can is be replaced with were in the past ???

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please elaborate, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

In past tense ‘is’ commonly changes to ‘was’ and ‘are’ commonly changes to ‘were’.

Examples: Where is my cat?   Past tense example: where was my cat?

Second example: where are my keys?  Past tense example: where were my keys?

I’m sure their are exceptions but I believe in general this stands true. Hope it helps!